# JavaScript Inicialização de Objetos

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Eu sou novo em JavaScript, e estou usando um *framework* Restangular escrito com AngularJs para requisições HTTPS.
Estou tendo muita dificuldades em inicializar um objeto literal, com a seguinte estrutura:

```
$scope.niveisDeAcesso = [
    {nivel:"LISTAR", selected: false},
    {nivel:"ADICIONAR", selected: false},
    {nivel:"EDITAR", selected: false},
    {nivel:"EXCLUIR", selected: false}
];
```

nesse trecho eu inicializado um objeto:

```
$scope.perfilDeAcesso = {};
```

aqui eu inicializado um *array* dentro do meu objeto:

```
$scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso = [];
```

a estrutura do meu objeto no final deve ser mais ou menos essa:

```
perfilDeAcesso = {itensPerfilDeAcesso[]}
```

e itensperfilDeAcesso deve ter uma estrutura semelhante à:

```
itemPerfilDeAcesso = { itemDeAcesso: {...}, niveisDeAcesso: [...]}
```

O meu problema

> Cannot set property xxx of undefined

esta em inicializar o `itensPerfilDeAcesso`, para que eu possa receber o `itemDeAcesso`:

```
Restangular.all('itemdeacesso').getList().then(function(itens) { 
    for (var int = 0; int < itens.length; int++) {
        $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int].itemDeAcess = 
            UtilService.limparDados(itens[int]);
        $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int].niveisDeAcesso = 
            angular.copy($scope.niveisDeAcesso);
    } 
})
```

Comment: Oi, Luiz, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Por favor, confira o guia http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque resolve um problema especifico do AP e não servira mais ninguém no futuro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como `$scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso` é um array vazio, `$scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int]` retorna `undefined`. Você deve inicializá-lo como um objeto vazio antes de atribuir propriedades ao mesmo:

```
for (var int = 0; int < itens.length; int++) {
    $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int] = {}; // inicialização do objeto
    $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int].itemDeAcess = 
        UtilService.limparDados(itens[int]);
    $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int].niveisDeAcesso = 
        angular.copy($scope.niveisDeAcesso);
}
```

Podemos também reescrever este código de forma mais coesa utilizando a sintaxe literal de objeto:

```
for (var int = 0; int < itens.length; int++) {
    $scope.perfilDeAcesso.itensPerfilDeAcesso[int] = {
        itemDeAcess: UtilService.limparDados(itens[int]),
        niveisDeAcesso: angular.copy($scope.niveisDeAcesso)
    };
}
```

Comment: pesquisei muito e não achei nada, com três caracteres eu resolvia meu problema, obrigado!